# Exporting a Crosstab out of Python into Excel--I am losing my row indexes/names

Tags: python

I am writing some code to count the number of three pointers an NBA player has made through the season, aggregated by game. (For example, Zach Lavine has had one game with 11 3-pointers made. That part works great. [image: Crosstab]

`threes=pd.crosstab(df_subset['PLAYER_NAME'], df_subset['FG3M'])`

Problem is when I export this to excel I only see my columns and not the row names associated with players anymore (index)

`threes.to_excel (r'C:\Users\three.xlsx', index = False, header=True)`

[image: results]

I have looked around and tried googling my way out of this to no avail.  Anyone help?  Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('threes.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
threes.reset_index().to_excel(writer,sheet_name = '1', index = False)
writer.save()
```

This did the trick.

[image]